# how to get friend fields on Facebook .net API

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying this but getting `"Unknown path components"` exception

this syntax works fine on Graph Explorer, I don't now why it is not working here.

thanks

Here' my code:

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
dynamic friends = client.Get("me/friends.fields(id,name,gender)", new { limit = "5000", offset = "0" });
```

Answer (score 0):

its maybe useful

```
   public static DataTable arkadasListe()
    {
         DataTable dtableArkadasTablosu = new DataTable("friends");
        dtableArkadasTablosu.Columns.Add("name", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dtableArkadasTablosu.Columns.Add("id", Type.GetType("System.String"));

        face.client.AccessToken = face.accesstoken;/
        var param = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        param["fields"] = "friends";
        if (face.client.AccessToken==null)
        {
            return dtableArkadasTablosu;

        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(face.client.AccessToken))
        {

            return dtableArkadasTablosu;
        }
        Facebook.JsonObject a = (Facebook.JsonObject)face.client.Get("me", param);




        if (a.Count==1)
        {
            return dtableArkadasTablosu;//bos tabloyu gonder
        }

        Facebook.JsonObject arr = (Facebook.JsonObject)a[1];//its friend list
        var arrs = (Facebook.JsonObject)arr;



        foreach (var friend in (JsonArray)arr["data"])//friends are in the data key
        {
            DataRow drowEklenecek = dtableArkadasTablosu.NewRow();//tablomuzdan yenı bır satır turetıyoruz

            string Id = (string)(((JsonObject)friend)["id"]).ToString();
            string Name = (string)(((JsonObject)friend)["name"]).ToString();

            drowEklenecek["name"] = Name;
            drowEklenecek["id"] = Id;
            dtableArkadasTablosu.Rows.Add(drowEklenecek);



        }

        return dtableArkadasTablosu;//dongu bıttıgınde arkadaslarımızı barındıran tablo hazır demektır.tabloyu gonder.


    }
```

Comment: face.client.AccessToken = face.accesstoken;/ selam birader face nerden geliyor birader hangi dll kullanıyon